# After Spring boot upgrade getting An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven

After upgrading the Spring-boot version to 2.3.0.RELEASE and adding mongoclient() bean in mongoConfig class getting below error -
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(DefaultClusterFactory.java:85)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/connection/ClusterId;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ServerSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Lcom/mongodb/MongoCredential;Lcom/mongodb/event/CommandListener;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mongodb/MongoDriverInformation;Ljava/util/List;)V
```

The method's class, com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.4/mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar!/com/mongodb/internal/connection/DefaultClusterableServerFactory.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.0.5/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/com/mongodb/internal/connection/DefaultClusterableServerFactory.class
```

Below is my POM -

```
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <spring-boot.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>

    <commons-csv.version>1.6</commons-csv.version>
    <apache-poi.version>4.0.1</apache-poi.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.7</jackson.version>
    <lombok.verison>1.18.4</lombok.verison>
    <jsr305.version>3.0.2</jsr305.version>
    <commons-lang.version>3.8.1</commons-lang.version>
    <modelmapper.version>2.3.2</modelmapper.version>
    <guava.version>27.0.1-jre</guava.version>
    <mongobee.version>0.13</mongobee.version>
    <mongodb.version>3.11.2</mongodb.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.10.5</jjwt.version>

    <junit-platform.version>1.6.2</junit-platform.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit-jupiter.version>
    <hamcrest.version>2.1</hamcrest.version>
    <mockito.version>2.23.4</mockito.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.failsafePlugin.version>2.22.1</maven.failsafePlugin.version>
    <maven.surefirePlugin.version>2.22.1</maven.surefirePlugin.version>
    <springfox-swagger2-version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger2-version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.4</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-csv.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${apache-poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache-poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
       <!--  <version>${commons-lang.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.verison}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${jackson.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${jackson.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${jackson.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mongobee</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongobee</artifactId>
        <version>${mongobee.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jacoco</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0.17289</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0.17289</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0.17289</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.XYZ.172113</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     </dependencies>

     <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java-jacoco</artifactId>
                        <version>5.11.0.17289</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.jacoco.core</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Below is MongDB Config file -

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xx.xx.xx.repository"})
 @EnableMongoAuditing
 public class MongoConfig {

private static final String CHANGE_LOGS_PACKAGE = "com.xx.xx.xx.config.changelogs";

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
private String mongoURI;

@Bean
public Mongobee mongobee(final MongoClient mongoClient,
                         final MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory,
                         final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    final Mongobee mongobee = new Mongobee(mongoClient);
    mongobee.setDbName(mongoDbFactory.getMongoDatabase().getName());
    mongobee.setMongoTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    mongobee.setChangeLogsScanPackage(CHANGE_LOGS_PACKAGE);
    return mongobee;
}

@Bean 
  public MongoClient mongoClient() { 
      
      return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoURI));
      
    }
```

Comment: One of the problems I see is that you are managing a whole range of versions of depend libraries yourself, instead of letting Spring Boot do this. I suspect that due to this you are running into incompatible versions being used.

Comment: I tried by commenting all version declaration, but still facing same issue.

Comment: Commenting the version declarations won't help as you are still managing some other dependencies which probably pull in older/newer (at least incompatible) versions.